# Output problem with Chinese characters in r console, r version 4

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

> After updated to r version 4, the output of Chinese characters were displayed in Unicode in r console. My questions is how to let it properly display the Chinese character.

> In my older version, r 3.6.1, it worked perfectly with the following locale:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.16

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1

> print("我")
[1] "我"
```

> However, using the updated r, it cannot print the Character properly. I  followed the solutions on the internet and tried to change the locale but did not solve the problem.

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.4

> print("我")
[1] "\u6211"


> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chs") 
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chs") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "chs" cannot be honored



> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "zh_CN.utf-8")
[1] "zh_CN.utf-8/zh_CN.utf-8/zh_CN.utf-8/C/zh_CN.utf-8/en_US.UTF-8"
> print("我")
[1] "\u6211"
```

I suspect that this is not a problem due to the locale issue, since in the older r version, the locale was the same as the new version, but it had no problem displaying the characters.

Would any one help with that? Really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I also run into the same problem using R 4.0.4. And this is a bug which has been reported to R team. The bug is supposed to be fixed in the next R release so I roll back to R 4.0.3.

For more details, please refer to this post:

[issue with print()ing multibyte characters on R 4.0.4](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/issue-with-print-ing-multibyte-characters-on-R-4-0-4-td4767776.html)

Answer (score 1):

Today new patch (r80061) for R 4.0.4 was released. The bug with characters was fixed.

> The change to the internal table in R 4.0.4 for iswprint has been
> reverted: it contained some errors in printability of ‘East Asian’
> characters.

```
> print("我")
[1] "我"
```

Answer (score 1):

for more detail, the new version called
R version 4.0.4 Patched (2021-03-05 r80086)
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html